# Angular Js and Trigger.io - Can't follow a link on Android that works on iOS

Tags: android, angularjs, trigger.io

I am using AngularJS with Trigger.io to develop a mobile application for both iOS and Android.

When I try to open a link that looks like this:

```
<a ng-href="#/offers/{{featured_offer.Id}}"></a>
```

It works perfectly fine on iOS, but on Android I get this message in the trigger console, and the link is not navigated to:

```
[WARNING] Attempted to open a URL which could not be handled: unsafe:content://io.trigger.forge722b6464a0e211e2ba9d12313d00dc45/src/index.html#/offers/8
```

How can I get this to work in Android the same as it works in iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like Angular adds unsafe: to url schemes it doesn't recognise, I think you want to include something like:

```
app.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|content):/);
});
```

Which adds content: to the accepted url schemes.

Comment: That was indeed it. I figured this out just after finally posting the question, but had to wait 8 hours to answer because I don't have enough reputation. So it goes to you!

Comment: The method btw has been renamed to `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, specifically with trying to display an img with a src of a file returned by forge.file.getImage.  Angular adds unsafe: to the content: prefix of the local img URL, and as connorhd said, you need to add content: to the url whitelist.

Note that compileProvider's API has changed with recent versions of Angular, so I'm commenting here in case anyone else finds an updated version of this workaround useful.

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', 
function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|content|blob):|data:image|/);
    // note: you'll also have to do imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist if you want to use general links as well as ng-src on images.
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem just add sanitizer in you config.xml

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
]);
```